# ServiceStack - is there an up-to date, complete documentation?

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to wrap my head around ServiceStack, and while it claims that it has really good documentation, it doesn't seem to be the case so far. Is there a documentation that actually says which interfaces/base classes to use, and what do they do ?

Just.. have a bunch of quesitons, and can find very few answers.. A [new API design](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-API) shows an example of DTO implementing IReturn interface, and service inheriting from Service - but there's no explanation if this is the preferred way now, is it required to implement IReturn, how to deal with POST/GET/etc, etc, etc..

Any links would be appreciated.

And yes, I have samples, but for example they don't have anything on this IReturn interface.. and samples won't beat the documentation anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find all the [documentation for the ServiceStack Web Framework on the wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki)

[ServiceStack's new API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) was just [released this week](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Release-Notes) which already contain the answers to all your questions. I would **go back and read them in-full** but I'll extract the snippets that answers your questions:

### Is there a documentation that actually says which interfaces/base classes to use, and what do they do?

Under the **Introducing the New API** section is:

The new API design simplifies the existing IService and IRestService **with this single unified interface**:

```
public interface IService {}
```

That is now able to **handle both RPC Service and Rest Service requests in a single class**. The interface is just used as a Marker interface that ServiceStack uses to find, register and auto-wire your existing services. A convenience concrete **Service** class is also included which contains easy access to ServiceStack's providers

### A new API design shows an example of DTO implementing IReturn interface, and service inheriting from Service - but there's no explanation if this is the preferred way now

The heading at the top of the wiki reads:

#### Recommended for future Web Service Development

As the new API Design offers many benefits over the existing API, **we're recommending its use for any new web service development**. It will take us some time, but we intend to port all the old examples to adopt the new API ourselves. **One reason** to still prefer the older API is if you also wanted to support SOAP clients and endpoints which still requires the strict-ness enforced by the previous approach.

Under the **Inspiration** heading reads:

The beauty of this proposal was that it already **fitted perfectly with ServiceStack's existing message-based semantics** which meant we were able to implement it in record time without any disruption or breaking changes to the existing code-base. The result is that **you can now start creating new services along side your existing services** and they'll both **continue to work seamlessly side-by-side**.

### is it required to implement IReturn

Under the heading **Calling Services from a Typed C# Client** is:

lets say you take the normal route of copying the DTOs (in either source of binary form) so you have something like this on the client:

```
[Route("/reqstars")]
public class AllReqstars : IReturn<List<Reqstar>> { }
```

The code on the client now just becomes:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUri);
List<Reqstar> response = client.Get(new AllReqstars());
```

Which makes a GET web request to the /reqstars route. When a custom route is not present on the client it automatically falls back to using ServiceStack's pre-defined routes.

Finally you can also use the previous more explicit client API (**ideal for when you don't have the IReturn<> marker**):

```
var response = client.Get<List<Reqstar>>("/reqstars");
```

All these APIs have async equivalents which you can use instead, when you need to.

### how to deal with POST/GET/etc,

The entire API docs is effectively about explaining how Post's Get's work. You have a `client.Get()` on the client which calls the `Get()` on the server, or falls back to using `Any()` if it doesn't exist.

The [bottom of the Wiki](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api) page goes through how to manually port your services from an older API to the newer one.

And here are some examples using the new API:

- [The Razor Rockstars Service](http://razor.servicestack.net/rockstars)
- [The Home Page TODOs example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/NewApiTodos.cs)
- [The Comprehensive test suite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/RazorRockstars.Console.Files/ReqStarsService.cs)